# Google JS not loading

Tags: windows-7, hosts

I'm having an issue with a computer, for some reason it won't display correctly some Google products (Google Fonts Webpage, Google REcaptcha, Google Map overlay tools, Google account button dropbox no matter the browser I'm using.

**The symptoms**

- Google Fonts displayed the correct way on Website, but fonts.google.com not displayed correctly [Google Fonts screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZPT0.jpg)
- Google Map displayed, but not overlay toolbar (Street vue, Satelitte vue) displays.
- Google managed Recaptcha simply not displayed [No recaptcha](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PLbm.jpg)
- Google search engine works fine, but I can't click on my account button (no drop box appears even for just loggin out)
- I can access Google Webmaster tools and Google Analytics with no problem.
- YouTube displays fine
- Gmail displays fine

**What have been done to tried to fix the problem**

- I made sure JS is working
- I have tried with a complete FireFox reset and SafeMode restart.
- I've removed AddBlocker
- All browsers related problem (Chrome, FireFox, IE, Opera) on the computer.
- I've tried with deactivated my firewall and antivirus
- I've clear browsers cache and Cookies
- Browsers are up to date
- Antivirus (BitDefender) is Up to date
- I've done complete scan with BitDefender (normal mode ans SafeMode)
- Only happens on one computer (other computers on the same LAN works fine with those Google things)
- Have checked if HOSTS file contain a redirection on any Google URL (nothing there)
- Have tried with antivirus and Fire Wall Off (not fixed the problem)
- No use of Proxy or VPN
- I am using Windows 7 OS (since a long time with no problem of that kind)
- I've set ALL Windows services to ON
- I've uninstalled all most recents softwares installed since the last days (clean uninstall).

It seems like some URLs for Google JS and Google CSS are blocked on that computer only.

Anyone can help me with this ?

Comment: Does it happen with a new profile?